# why isn't chatterbot working in this code?

Tags: spacy, chatterbot

I have a code that imports chatterbot.
I  run
python -m spacy download en
python terminal1.py.

terminal1.py
''''
    import spacy

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot

# Uncomment the following lines to enable verbose logging
# import logging
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Create a new instance of a ChatBot
bot = ChatBot(
    'Terminal',
     storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
     logic_adapters=[
        'chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation',
        'chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter',
        'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch'
    ],
    database_uri='sqlite:///database.db'
)

print('Type something to begin...')

# The following loop will execute each time the user enters input
while True:
    try:
        user_input = input()

        bot_response = bot.get_response(user_input)

        print(bot_response)

    # Press ctrl-c or ctrl-d on the keyboard to exit
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit):
        break
```

''''

I get the error

OSErrror: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

Can some one help me fix this problem and in the process run the code. I will be much thankful.

Answer (score 0):

try to run this command `pip install spacy && python -m spacy download en` this will link en model.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ran the commands. It still gives the same error. This is a windows 8.1 machine.

Comment: Follow [this](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2941), may be you can get some help.

Comment: Followed the link and the commands. pip list shows en-core-web-sm. Still the same error: Can't find model 'en'